# Saying Ritzei after Shekiyah

Tags: halacha, shabbat, bentching, sunset-shekia

*HoRav Yisroel Belsky Shlit"a* (see *Mishna Berurah* 299:1) permits one to eat *סעודת שלישית* until 20 minutes after *Shekiyah*. Would someone still be able to say רצה if he started eating after *Shkekiyah* or is it too late?

Comment: Can you source your first sentence? I'm pretty sure "the Halacha" is not uniform about this issue.

Comment: Our Rav paskens saying רצה after סעודת שלישית as usually most of the meal is eaten before *Shekiya*. I cannot give this as an answer as I do not have his source for this. Note if Rosh Chodesh is on Sunday, then he has us say רצה and **not** Yaaleh V'yavo (I think unlike the Mishnah Brurah, but I do not have the citation). One cannot say both as that is a contradiction.

Comment: From my personal experience with Rabbi Belsky I would be surprised if he argued on rabbi Feinstein on this subject who disagreed with that mishna berurah to the degree of calling it a mistake and calling anyone who relies on it a poshea. So as Double said, can you source this claim?

Comment: Since the person is relying on the lenient opinion that it's still Shabbat, (otherwise he couldn't eat) then why would he not say רצה? he started eating on Shabbat.

Comment: @user6591 Where did RMF write that?

Comment: @Double O'Ch 4 69 6 His term was shogeg, not poshea. My bad.